# Is it possible to move the UIPageControl dots

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipagecontrol

I am trying to move the UIPageControl dots so they are not centered. Is this possible? I created my own PageControl class, but the bounds are show the width at 185. I can't seem to change the width to make it as wide as the UIWindow (320)?

Any suggestions?

```
CGRect currentBounds = self.bounds;  <--- always 185 width
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change the width. Simply move the control:

```
[self setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height]
```

Comment: I figured it out. The class I was using was setting the page control width to 185.